# serialization java freezing my program

Tags: java, java-io

I have a multiplayer game. 
I have a java socket server program already running.

Im sending strings to the socketserver which are recieved fine.

This is my sending and receiving class:

```
public class BaseServer 
{
    private String result = null;

    //for serializable class input stream
    ObjectInput input;


 // Declare client socket
    Socket clientSocket = null;         

 // Declare output stream and string to send to server 
    DataOutputStream os = null;


 // Declare input stream from server and string to store input received from server
    BufferedReader is = null;
    String responseLine;

//get ip
    String serverAddress ;                                    

// Create a socket on port 5000 and open input and output streams on that socket
public void  setUpNetwork(String serverAd)
{          
    try
    {
        serverAddress = serverAd;
        clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, 5000);

        //string
        os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());          
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        //serial
        input = new ObjectInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream() );

    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
    }      
}

/*
 * Used to communicate with server
 * takes message to send and the object expecting the response
 * 1 simple method to replace all but one of the below v1 methods
 */
public BaseSerialDataObjects serverTalk(String message, BaseSerialDataObjects serializableobject){
    sendStringMessage(message);

    try {

        switch(serializableobject.getClass().getSimpleName()){
        case "PlayerPositionsSerial":
            PlayerPositionsSerial serializableobject2 = (PlayerPositionsSerial) input.readObject();
            return serializableobject2;

        case "GameSettings": 
            return serializableobject = (GameSettings) input.readObject();

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

//Sends messages to the server
public void sendStringMessage(String message){
    // Write data to the socket
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null){
        try {                        
            os.writeBytes( message + "\n" );                                 
            }
        catch (UnknownHostException e){
            System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }   
    }
```

on both the return statements in the serverTalk() method the program freezes completely but doesn't seem to crash I dont know what is happening ?

my lecturer said when expolaining this topic:

```
ObjectInput input;
input = new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
serializableobject = ( cast ) input.readObject();
input.flush();
```

the input flush bit doesnt work and im not sure why its necessary.
when i try and include on the input its flagged up and advises me to cast it to outputstream

the classes im trying to move around are identical on the server and client which are here:

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class BaseSerialDataObjects implements Serializable{



}

/*
 * class for game settings
 * decided to split it and make it serializable incase of multi player 
 * thought this would be easier to standardise setting across multiple devices
 */
  public class GameSettings extends BaseSerialDataObjects{

//GameWide variables

    public String gameState;
    public int winningNumberOfLaps = 1;
    public String winString;            
    public long gameStartTime;
 }

 /*
 * this class will be used on the server and each player will on request
 * Receive a copy with player information
 */
 public class PlayerPositionsSerial extends BaseSerialDataObjects {

    //position 0 = name;
    //position 1 = angle;
    //position 2 = position x
    //position 3 = position y
    //position 4 = state

    //position 5 = state in relation to server
    public String[][] playersArray;
 }
```

Im really dissapointed i did have a really tedious set of string forward and back replys and thought just requesting this information would make everything alot more managable

server code just incase:

```
public class TCPserver implements Runnable 
{
static Socket server = null;
static String gameState = "menu";
static int numberOfConnectedPlayers = 0;

private static final int possibleNumberOfPlayers = 8;
private static final int amountOfPlayerInfoHeld = 6;
private int threadNumber;

private static GameSettings gameSettings = new GameSettings();

//position 0 = name;
//position 1 = angle;
//position 2 = position x
//position 3 = position y
//position 4 = state

//position 5 = state in relation to server
//POssible states: 
    // connected
static PlayerPositionsSerial positions = new PlayerPositionsSerial();

public static void main( String args[] )
{
   positions.playersArray = new String [possibleNumberOfPlayers][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld];

  // Declare a server socket and a client socket for the server
  ServerSocket service = null;

  // Try to open a server socket on port 5000
  try
   {
     service = new ServerSocket(5000);
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t0 = new Thread (new TCPserver(0));
       t0.start();
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t1 = new Thread (new TCPserver(1));
       t1.start();
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t2 = new Thread (new TCPserver(2));
       t2.start();      
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t3 = new Thread (new TCPserver(3));
       t3.start();
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t4 = new Thread (new TCPserver(4));
       t4.start();          
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t5 = new Thread (new TCPserver(5));
       t5.start();
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t6 = new Thread (new TCPserver(6));
       t6.start();          
        server = service.accept();
        Thread t7 = new Thread (new TCPserver(7));
       t7.start();
        /*server = service.accept();
        Thread t8 = new Thread (new TCPserver(8));
       t8.start();  */      


  }
  catch (IOException e)
   {
     System.out.println(e);
  }        


    }

public void run()
{
// Declare an input stream and String to store message from client      
    BufferedReader is;
    String line;

    // Declare an output stream to client       
   DataOutputStream os;

    String thr = Integer.toString(threadNumber);

  // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept
  // connections. Open input and output streams
  try
   {
        ObjectOutput output;
        output = new ObjectOutputStream( server.getOutputStream() );

        is = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
                                     server.getInputStream()));



       //if( (line = is.readLine()) != null )
        while( (line = is.readLine()) != null )
        {
            if(line != null)
            {
                line = rules(line);

                switch(line){
                case "playertable": 
                    output.writeObject( positions );    

                    break;
                case "gamesettings": 
                    output.writeObject( gameSettings );
                    break;
                }
            }output.flush();

        }

        // Comment out/remove the stream and socket closes if server is to remain live. 

     is.close();

  }  
  catch (IOException e)
   {
     System.out.println(e);         
  }         
}

public TCPserver(int tNumber)
{
    threadNumber = tNumber;
}

private synchronized void changeArray(int row, int col, String value)
{
    positions.playersArray[row][col]  = value;
}

private synchronized String readArray(int row, int col)
{
    return positions.playersArray[row][col];
}   

private String rules(String lineIn)
{
    String returnString = "";
    try {
         String[] splitArray = lineIn.split("\\s+");

             switch(splitArray[0])
             {
                case "signIn":

                    positions.playersArray[threadNumber][0] = splitArray[1];
                    positions.playersArray[threadNumber][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld-1] = "connected";                       
                    addPlayer();
                    returnString = "gamesettings ";

                    break;
                case "ok":
                // just for reply, do nothing response heard "ok"
                    break;
                case "matchMake":
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld -1] = "matchmake";
                        gameSettings.gameState = "matchmake";
                        returnString = "playertable";
                    break;
                case "ready":

                    positions.playersArray[threadNumber][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld -1] = "ready";

                    returnString = "gamesettings";
                    break;

                case "requestStart":

                      boolean goAhead = true;
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfConnectedPlayers; i++)
                        {
                            if(positions.playersArray[i][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld-1] != "ready")
                            {
                                goAhead = false;
                            }
                        }                       

                        if(goAhead)
                        {
                            long start = System.currentTimeMillis( );
                            start = start + 10000;
                            gameSettings.gameStartTime = start;
                        }

                        returnString =  "gamesettings";
                        break;
                    case "getPos":
                        returnString = splitArray[0] + " ";

                        returnString  = "playertable";
                        break;
                    case "updatePos":

                        //heres where to notice crashes and check for wins etc...
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][1] = splitArray[1];
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][2] = splitArray[2];
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][3] = splitArray[3];
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][4] = splitArray[4];
                        returnString = "playertable";
                        break;
             }

    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

            System.err.println("error: " + ex);
    }

    return returnString;
}

public synchronized void addPlayer()
{
    numberOfConnectedPlayers++;
}

public synchronized int getNumberOfPlayers()
{
    return numberOfConnectedPlayers;
}

public synchronized void removePlayer()
{
    numberOfConnectedPlayers--;
}
}
```

any help on this would be massivly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward explanation for your problem would be that the server simply doesn't respond, which makes the client wait forever (`input.readObject()` will wait until some data is received). In your server code, you should make sure that you are in fact answering the client:

```
switch(line){
case "playertable": 
    output.writeObject( positions );    
    break;
case "gamesettings": 
    output.writeObject( gameSettings );
    break;
default:
    // You should throw an exception or output an error message here
}
```

One problem might e.g. be this other part of your server code:

```
returnString = "gamesettings ";
```

which will not match your `case "gamesettings"` because of the additional space.

Comment: @valardohearis OMG! lol i hope just removing that sorts it! brb :)

Comment: Thank you so much @valardohaeris! there was a few of those typos using strings. Ive been looking for a reason to use a enum because i havent really before would this be a could case? regardless of language im not sure if java supports enums?

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple kinds of input stread/reader on the same underlying socket input stream. As at least two of them are buffered, that cannot possibly work, because the buffering will 'steal' data from the other stream(s). If you want to use Object Serialization, use it for everything: get rid of the `DataInputStream` and the `BufferedReader`, and whatever writes that data at the sending end, and just use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: ok i will try that now what abot the input.flush() should i be concerned that its not working how my tutor said? will

Comment: thanks but that doesnt seem to matter everythings working fine now just with the spelling corrections and whitespace removal

Comment: Your tutor is mistaken, or more probably you misunderstood. There is no such thing as flushing the input in Java. Did he say, or mean, flush the *output?*

Comment: ObjectInput input;
input = new ObjectInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
serializableobject = ( cast ) input.readObject();
input.flush();

Comment: sorry that above which i put in my post clearer is exactly as the slides say

Comment: about the post it was a different post for a different problem sorry